# Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource - Cannot Find a Fix

Tags: php, mysql

I had this issue fixed but as I was trying to fix SQL vulnerabilities I created an error and started back from scratch, I'm stuck again at this issue and have absolutely no clue what to do. Please help.

```
<? 
ob_start();
include 'easygpt_config.php';
ob_end_clean();
if(isset($_POST['login'])){
$username= trim($_POST['username']);
$password = trim($_POST['password']);
if($username == NULL OR $password == NULL){
$final_report.="Please complete both fields";
$check_user_data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `username` = '$username'") or die(mysql_error());
}else{
if(mysql_num_rows($check_user_data) == 0){ 
$final_report.="This username does not exist";
}else{
$get_user_data = mysql_fetch_array($check_user_data) or die("A MySQL error has occurred.<br />Your Query: " . $your_query . "<br /> Error: (" . mysql_errno() . ") " . mysql_error());
if($get_user_data['password'] == $password){
$start_idsess = $_SESSION['username'] = "".$get_user_data['username']."";
$start_passsess = $_SESSION['password'] = "".$get_user_data['password']."";
$final_report.="<meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='0; URL=http://www.google.com>";
}}}}

if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && isset($_SESSION['password'])){ 
    }

?>
```

The line that is being listed as causing the error is line 12 which consist of:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($check_user_data) == 0){
```

Comment: You run the query in a separate block than what you use `mysql_num_rows`

Comment: Please use `mysqli_` functions instead of the deprecated `mysql_` functions.

Comment: Can you please advise a way to do so Marvin? I was going to switch my entire script to PDO, would that be an issue?

Comment: Looks like toy for hackers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With just some standard indentation it becomes very clear what's going on, as Explosion Pills already pointed out:

```
<?
ob_start();
include 'easygpt_config.php';
ob_end_clean();
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
    $username = trim($_POST['username']);
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);
    if ($username == NULL OR $password == NULL) {
        $final_report .= "Please complete both fields";
        $check_user_data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `username` = '$username'") or die(mysql_error());
    } else {
        if (mysql_num_rows($check_user_data) == 0) {
            $final_report .= "This username does not exist";
        } else {
            $get_user_data = mysql_fetch_array($check_user_data) or die("A MySQL error has occurred.<br />Your Query: " . $your_query . "<br /> Error: (" . mysql_errno() . ") " . mysql_error());
            if ($get_user_data['password'] == $password) {
                $start_idsess   = $_SESSION['username'] = "" . $get_user_data['username'] . "";
                $start_passsess = $_SESSION['password'] = "" . $get_user_data['password'] . "";
                $final_report .= "<meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='0; URL=http://www.google.com>";
            }
        }
    }
}
if (isset($_SESSION['username']) && isset($_SESSION['password'])) {
}
?>
```

You're executing the query (and thus setting `$check_user_data`) in the `if` block, and testing it in the `else` block.

Want to avoid this kind of mess in the future?  Indent your code manually or get one of the bazillion code editors that can handle that chore for you.  Or use one of the many online prettyprinting services (like [beta.phpformatter.com])(http://beta.phpformatter.com/).

And last but not least, stop using the deprecated mysql_ functions.  Deprecated, among other things means you **should not** use them in new code.

I'd also suggest to forget about the more modern mysqli_ successor and skip right away to [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) - it's a modern, well designed API, usable with several database engines and last but not least, it makes working with prepared statements a breeze, and prepared statements are probably the least expensive yet most effective defense against [sql injection](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: I'm switching to PDO, I just have never used it and since I'm building a plugin I want it to be perfect before I publicize it. Thanks for the tip on formatting the PHP, looks beautiful. Anything you can recommend that will help me with converting to PDO?

Comment: Well yet another reason to switch right now, releasing a brand new piece of code based on a condemned API would be very unwise.  Have a look at the PDO docs I referred to, or any of the tutorials online.  You'll see that PDO maps almost 1:1 on mysql_, you also open a connection, prepare a query and get its result set.  Shouldn't be hard to convert.  And formatting your code really isn't about beauty, it's totally functional as I wanted to show you: once the code is proeperly indented it instantly becomes obvious why it doesn't work, as I explained in my answer.

Comment: I was never even aware of the proper formatting, but even with it being more functional I must admit it looks a whole lot better as well.